# Target certain words with CSS?

Tags: css

This is kind of a theory question but I wonder whether it is possible or not.

So if you have a div with some content like...

```
<div>£100.00 - BUY</div>
```

Can you then target "£100.00" without targeting the rest?

So you can increase the font size of £100.00?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could target it by wrapping it in a `span` element:

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/D6E4L/)

```
<div><span class="price">$100.00</span> - BUY</div
```

Comment: @Alnitak I guess he just wanted to help. It's kind of the goal of this community, isn't it ? And he's quite right on with this answer.

Answer (score 5):

No, that can't be done without wrapping the desired text in another element, typically a `<span>`.

Comment: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) about pseudo-classes. There is indeed no pseudo-class to select the first word. You can select the first letter, but that won't help much here.

Comment: Yes, you can do `::first-letter`, or `::first-line`, but not `::first-word`.  I didn't bother suggesting pseudo-classes in the actual answer because the pseudo classes available are so specific that they won't help in the general case the way a `<span>` can.

Comment: In theory, one can also use a custom font in which digits and currency symbols are bigger than normal letters:) But I don't think that is a real option. Of course, `span` is the right thing for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

`<div><span id="price">£100.00</span> - BUY</div>`

### CSS

```css
#price {  
 font-size: 2em; // double of the current font  
}  

div {  
font-size: inherit; // get the font-size from the browser or the document.  
}
```

This will give the div a default font-size but the span with id price will have twice the font-size as the div.